# How to manage a public changelog in continuous delivery project?

Tags: maven, changelog, continuous-delivery

I plan to use continuous delivery for my project maven project but i'm unsure on how to actually manage the public changelog. Previously (regular sequential releases) i would write the changelog entry upfront and since i knew what release version would be expected i could just refer to that version. With CD this changes. I can no longer refer to a specific version since i'm doing CD without actually knowing the version upfront.

Are there any tools or workflows best practices for CD to manage a public changelog?

I know that i could just fetch the SCM log and generate a changelog using that information but i don't like to use SCM messages for a public (enduser friendly) changelog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own [changelog tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/changelog2html) which identifies git tags for a set of changes files. This information is then used to create the changelog.

This way i can use the git tag information and i'm still able to update previously created changelog entries.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that SCM log messages are too noisy for a changelog. I would recommend reserving the tag messages for your releases as the additions to your changelog.